# Jenkins configuration matrix triggering multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a configuration matrix with multiple values and anytime I select multiple values they create multiple build jobs.
Want I want to have is to be able to select multiple values but Jenkins only creating one build job.
Does anyone know where and what I have to modify in the configuration tab for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

☑️ *This project is parameterized* lets you **<kbd>Add Parameter   ▼</kbd>**  more than once for one project/job. The same applies to pipeline `input`, e.g.:

```groovy
    stages {
        stage('Parameters') {
            steps {
                input( message: 'Enter or select parameter values:',
                    parameters: [
                        string( name: 'StringParam1', defaultValue: 'StringValue1', trim: true ),
                        booleanParam( name: 'BooleanParam' )
                    ]
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

See `https://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/pipeline-syntax/` → ***Steps*** → *Sample step*: *input: Wait for interactive input* → **<kbd>Advanced...</kbd>** → *Parameters* → **<kbd>Add   ▼</kbd>** for samples of the various input types.

Comment: additionally `parameters{}` block can be used if DSL is used

Comment: @jcmendez Additional parameter sections in a pipeline cause additional  parameter input pages (one per `parameters` section) when building the project.

Comment: An input for Matrix generate the same behaviour. However I understand that the user is trying to have multiple parameters rather than a matrix behavior